# How to merge conflicted file in your branch only in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I have two branches branch-A and Integration. When I create pull request for Integration branch I see conflicts in one file. I don't want to merge whole branch to resolve conflicts, I just want that conflicted file to be merged into branch-A and resolve the conflicts.

Is there any way that I can just merge that conflicted file ONLY to branch-A from Integration branch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if merging only one file is a good idea, but If you really want to do that, just create patch with changes to this file and apply it on *branch-A*:

1. Checkout *branch-A*:

   ```
   $ git checkout branch-A
   ```
2. Create patch:

   ```
   $ git format-patch branch-A..Integration <file_path> --stdout > changes.patch
   ```
3. Apply it:

   ```
   $ git am --3way < changes.patch
   ```
4. Applying patch will stop because conflict, resolve it and resume applying:

   ```
   $ git add <file_path>
   $ git am --continue
   ```

Comment: Thanks @qzb, let try that.